# How to suppress IWYU system header errors?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, iwyu

When building with IWYU enabled I receive many errors regarding missing members and undeclared identifiers e.g:
'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:153:8: error: no member named 'int8_t' in the global namespace
using::int8_t;'

I built and installed IWYU from: https://include-what-you-use.org/downloads/
Using: -DIWYU_LLVM_ROOT_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm

Please could you suggest what I've got wrong to cause these errors?
Failing that, how can I suppress these (false?) errors?

Programming with C++17.
Using include-what-you-use 0.10 based on clang version 6.0.0.
Compiling using clang 6.0.0.
Builing using cmake 3.11.1.
Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.4.

Answer (score 0):

Appears I was pointing to the wrong llvm path. As I was using the version of clang installed by homebrew the set path should have read:
-DIWYU_LLVM_ROOT_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/